# How can I load new material.map.image.src in background and then render

Tags: javascript, image, three.js, render, on-the-fly

I am trying to change material.map.image.src on the fly when interacting with mouse, but each time i set the new image, the scene jitters while the image loads. to show the problem at its worst, i have linked the change to the onMouseMove event.

A working jittery example is here: [Example](http://www.numpty.co.uk/mousemovejitter.html)

I am doing this in the onMouseMove event which is probably the wrong approach and my code is crude as I have tried to learn javascript in order to use three.js: monkey see, monkey do style.

Can anyone help me make the **intersects[i].object.material.map.image.src = "/images/maisy.jpg";** work in the background...?

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

        for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
            intersects[i].object.material.map.image.src = "/images/maisy.jpg";
            exit; // ensures foreground object is adjusted and not all behind it.
        }
    }
```

It is probably obvious to you all, but it has taken me some time to get this far and now I'm stumped.

Many thanks in advance to all who read,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your init code you would do:

```
maisyTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/maisy.jpg" );
```

with `maisyTex` being a global variable. Then in your code you would just do:

```
intersects[i].object.material.map = maisyTex;
```

Comment: Thanks @gaitat, this answers my question exactly. I probably should have added that this is a demo to show the problem and that my production version will need to load images from thousands of files depending on the object user data attribute. As I cannot pre-initialise them all. I think I will have the same issue. I was hoping to use a function to background load the image, then only render after a callback tells me I have a loaded image. Does this sound like the right approach?

Comment: asynchronous loading (which is the case here) is the same as backgrounding a process in your case. But with thousands of images it will not be easy to avoid hickups. I would, in addition, use a setTimout() functions that loads images every few seconds.

Comment: I've been at this for weeks on and off @Gaitat and you have put me straight back on track. Many thanks!!!